# python module keep crashing

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a doorbell with a raspberry pi zero. When I press the button it will send a picture to telegram. The module works but, after a few pressed the button the module crash.

and see an error in terminal:

*** Error in `python3': double free or corruption (out): 0x01f306e8 ***

or I get this error:

> python3: malloc.c:2406: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top
>   (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE &&
>   prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==
>   0)' failed.

I hope somebody know how to fix the problem 
thanks alot!

python

```
import time
import random
import datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
from picamera import PiCamera
import pygame
from settings import getstring
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

camera = PiCamera()

bot = telepot.Bot('TOKEN')
ring = 'tones/doorbell.mp3'
pin = 22
pressed = 0

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(ring)

def sendpic(chat_id):
    camera.resolution = (1024, 768)
    camera.capture('snapshots/test.jpg')
    photo = open('snapshots/test.jpg', 'rb')
    bot.sendPhoto(chat_id, photo)

def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print('Got command: %s' % command)

    if command == '/roll':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, random.randint(1,6))
    elif command == '/time':
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, str(datetime.datetime.now()))
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

        sendpic(chat_id)

MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print('I am listening ...')

# Define GPIO -pins as standard
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Define pin X as input and enable internal resistors
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# function for button press
while True:
    input_state = GPIO.input(pin)
    if input_state == False:
        pressed = 1
    else:
        if pressed == 1:
            print('Someone at the door.')
            pygame.mixer.music.play()

            pressed = 0

while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```